# Books for Numerical linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I'am looking for some books for studying Numerical linear algebra methods. It could be on english or russian ​​languages, and Maple or Matlab examples preferable, but it also can be C/C++/Formal code. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this question might be more suitable for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does it have to involve programming? I took several courses in e.g. numerical linear algebra without touching Matlab.

Comment: Numerical linear algebra is not the right use case for Maple. Maple is more suitable for symbolic/exact computations e.g. over $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$, finite fields, and algebraic numbers. MATLAB, however, is (one of) the right tools for computational numerical linear algebra.

Answer (score 7):

My favorites are Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan and Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau. Together they cover all the important aspects of the field.

Answer (score 3):

Take a preview at http://tinyurl.com/6tskfks,

and also [this](http://www.math.utah.edu/books/calc2-maple/bg.pdf).

I would also look at the resource Maplesoft has [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/ebooks/aem/index.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521880688)

Comment: Wow, that one is great, is there anything like that for Maple/Matlab, it could be priceless for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @nilly Sorry i have not read any matlab books. I refer to the above book when i need to find algorithms and implement them using Matlab help. though u can find lots of similar matlab books not sure if they are of equal standing here http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=matlab&x=0&y=0#/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=matlab+numerical+methods&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Amatlab+numerical+methods